# C# Windows Forms: Save & Save As Woes

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

This is really frustrating me. I'm new to C Sharp so looking for some assistance. My Save/Save As is totally fubar.

Two questions really:

How do I save changes to an existing file without popping a save dialog? If I click save it pops a dialog which is fine so I save it, then make some changes and click Save again it pops a dialog rather than just saving the file to the name already given.

How do I show the filename rather than the full path in the save as dialog? It shows as File Name: C:\Users\username\desktop\save\filename.xml

This is in MainForm.cs.

```
private void biFileSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save diagram
        EditorForm editForm = this.ActiveDiagramForm;
        if (editForm != null)
        {
            if (!editForm.HasFileName)
            {
                if (this.saveEditorDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog.FileName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog.FileName);
            }
        }

private void biFileSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save As diagram
        EditorForm editForm = this.ActiveDiagramForm;
        if (editForm != null)
        {
            if (editForm.HasFileName)
            {
                this.saveEditorDialog.FileName = editForm.FileName;
            }
            if (this.saveEditorDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog.FileName);
                string strFileName = this.saveEditorDialog.FileName;

            }

        }
    }
```

This is in EditForm.cs

```
 public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fileName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileName = value;
            this.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.fileName);
        }
    }

    public bool HasFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.fileName != null && this.fileName.Length > 0);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Thank you for helping me on this so quickly! My Save works as expected now, however it introduced a strange issue with Save As (code above).

If I open a file (test.xml) that I have saved, then click Save As (name it test2.xml) it saves to the new file. BUT, when I open that test.xml again and make changes and click Save it saves those changes to the test2.xml. Very strange...any ideas?

Comment: Care to add screenshots or comments to the code explaining what is happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: Since I'm new to Stackoverflow I can't post images, but I edited my initial question maybe that will help?

Comment: You'll want to add the editForm.FileName = this.saveEditorDialog.FileName; line to the SaveAs method as well.

Comment: yep, figured that out works great! thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where in code is FileName set? From the sample you've posted, I don't see it being set anywhere, but perhaps it is elsewhere. This may work:

```
private void biFileSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save diagram
        EditorForm editForm = this.ActiveDiagramForm;
        if (editForm != null)
        {
            if (!editForm.HasFileName)
            {
                if (this.saveEditorDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog.FileName);
                    editForm.FileName = this.saveEditorDialog.FileName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response it works great. However, that introduces a different issue with Save As which I borked also :). I'll answer your question as well in my Edit.

Answer (score 1):

1) The Save `dialog box` will simply return the file path the user wishes to save to. Using this path, you can then perform your save function. If you want to save to the current document, simply skip the dialog box and perform your save function with a cached version of the chosen path.

For example, in your form, have a variable:

```
string currentFilePath = "";
```

When the user first opens a Save Dialog Box, fill that variable with the path the user chose.
The next time the user saves (instead of `save as`), perform a check:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFilePath))
   //save method using currentFilePath as the path to save to
```

2) You need to set the `FileName` somewhere. You can then use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) on the `FileName` to get just the name and extension.